# Ktor-websocket library do nothing when trying to receive data on client

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I am currently trying to connect our Kotlin Multiplatform Project to websockets. I would like to use ktor-websockets library to receive some updates from our backend but onfortunately when I run this code, nothing happens:

```
client.webSocket(
            port = 80,
            method = HttpMethod.Get,
            host = "https://uat-betws.sts.pl",
            path = "/ticket?token=eyJzdWIiOiI0ZmY5Y2E1Mi02ZmEwLTRiYWYtODlhYS0wODM1NGE2MTU0YjYiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTk4MDAwNzgsImV4cCI6MTYxOTgwMzY3OH0.oIaXH-nFDpMklp4FSJWMtsM7ECSIfuNF99tTQxiEALM"
        )
        {
            for (message in incoming) {
                message as? Frame.Text ?: continue
                val receivedText = message.readText()
                println(receivedText)
            }
            // Consume all incoming websockets on this url
            this.incoming.consumeAsFlow().collect {
                logger.d("Received ticket status websocket of type ${it.frameType.name}")
                if (it is Frame.Text) {
                    Json.decodeFromString<TicketStatusResponse>(it.readText())
                }
            }
        }
```

Does somebody have any experience with ktor-websockets library? There is almost no documentation so maybe I am doing something wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/websocket-client.html) says

`Ktor provides Websocket client support for the following engines: CIO, OkHttp, Js.`

This means that it works only on JVM/JS, you're probably targeting iOS. It's not yet supported, you can follow issue [KTOR-363](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-363) for updates

For sure the team is working on it, but for now you had to implement it by yourself using expect/actual, you can check out [official example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/connect-to-platform-specific-apis.html#example-send-and-receive-messages-from-a-websocket)

An other possible problem in your code: `host` shouldn't include `https://`, if you're using ssl, you should add an other parameter:

```
request = {
    url.protocol = URLProtocol.WSS
}
```

Or use `client.wss(...)` - which is just a short form for the same operation